# How to determine number of function arguments dynamically

Tags: c++11

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class test
{
public:
    typedef std::function<bool(int)> Handler;

    void handler(Handler h){h(5);}
};

class test2
{
public:
      template< typename Ret2, typename Ret, typename Class, typename Param>
      inline Ret2 MemFn(Ret (Class::*f)(Param), int arg_num)
      {
          if (arg_num == 1)
              return std::bind(f, this, std::placeholders::_1);
      }

    bool f(int x){ std::cout << x << std::endl; return true;}
};

int main()
{
    test t;
    test2 t2;

    t.handler(t2.MemFn<test::Handler>(&test2::f, 1));


    return 0;
}
```

It works as expected.

I would like to be able to call this:

```
t.handler(t2.MemFn<test::Handler>(&test2::f));
```

instead of

```
t.handler(t2.MemFn<test::Handler>(&test2::f, 1));
```

Basically I need `MemFn` to determine in runtime what `Handler` expects as the number of arguments.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You may create some type_traits to have your info, something like:

```
template <typename T> struct function_trait;

template <typename Ret, typename ... Args>
struct function_trait<std::function<Ret(Args...)>>
{
    static constexpr std::size_t args_count = sizeof...(Args);
};
```

And so your method may look like:

```
template<typename Ret2, typename Ret, typename Class, typename Param>
inline Ret2 MemFn(Ret (Class::*f)(Param))
{
    if (function_trait<Ret2>::args_count == 1)
        return std::bind(f, this, std::placeholders::_1);
    throw std::runtime_error("invalid number of arguments");
}
```